# Compute the "fill rate" of a field in Elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch

I would like to compute the ratio of fields that have a value in my index.

I managed to count how many documents miss the field:

```
GET profiles/_search
{
  "aggs": {
    "profiles_wo_country": {
      "missing": {
        "field": "country"
      }
    }
  },
  "size": 0
}
```

I also managed to count how many documents have the filed:

```
GET profiles/_search
{
  "query": {
    "filtered": {
      "query": {"match_all": {}},
      "filter": {
        "exists": {
          "field": "country"
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "size": 0
}
```

Naturally I can also get the total number of documents in the index. How can I compute the ratio?

Comment: `(exists_count / total_docs) * 100` or `((1 - missing_count) / total_docs) * 100` ?

Comment: @Val Right... But how do I code it into an ES query/aggregation/etc.?

Comment: What ES version are you running?

Answer (score 1):

An easy way to get the numbers you need out of a query is using the following query

```
POST profiles/_search?filter_path=hits.total,aggregations.existing.doc_count
{
  "size": 0,
  "aggs": {
    "existing": {
      "filter": {
        "exists": {
          "field": "tag"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

You'll get an response like this one:

```
{
   "hits": {
      "total": 37258601
   },
   "aggregations": {
      "existing": {
        "doc_count": 9287160
      }
   }
}
```

And then in your client code, you can simply do

```
fill_rate = (aggregations.existing.doc_count / hits.total) * 100
```

And you're good to go.

Comment: This makes sense, but I was wondering is is possible to do directly? Get a plot in Kibana?